# ClickHouse: Can a user change his own password?

Tags: clickhouse

In ClickHouse, is it possible to GRANT a user for changing his own password but without allowing him to alter his privileges nor the privileges/password of other users?

If I set `GRANT ALTER USER TO myuser`, I will allow myuser to change the password and the privileges of all the users. And that I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood the final goal is to avoid compromising/sharing a 'fresh' client password.

I would suggest storing hashed passwords instead of plain text - see for details [user settings - user_name/password](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings-users/#user-namepassword).

In this case,

- user should send to the admin the hashed password
- and admin set it up by yourself by using [ALTER USER](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/user/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think it's a solution that I can apply at the end. However I would prefer the user to do it himself and not relying on an admin user to do it. But if it's not possible, I will probably implement your solution. Thanks again